# powerpivot configration

Tags: sql-server, powerpivot

i installed sql server 2008 and SharePoint 2010 and finished the installation of the pivot but when i clicked start - 1 all programs -sql server 2008 - configuration tools - 
(but the only thing exist inside it is sql server installation center )

the pivot configuration is not exist is there any other place that have **pivot configuration
 tools** or what should i do to find that pivot configuration tool should i reinstall it ???

Comment: i found that the sql server should be sql 2012 but i want to know is there is any other way to use it on mine ??

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server 2012 is not necessary.

The configuration for PowerPivot in SharePoint 2010 is inside SharePoint Central Admin. (primarily PowerPivot Service, but also Excel Services, Secure Store).You'll have to have some understanding about SharePoint Administration. In particular, go to your SharePoint CA Site (under start-programs-SharePoint Tools), System Settings, Services On Server. Then click powerpivot to get the farm config. thats the start. good luck.